# SQL script to return the multiple applicants and the application statuses

Tags: sql

I appreciate it if someone can advise me on solving the following problem.
I have a table called applicants with following

| Id | Year | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 2019 | Fail |
| BB | 2019 | Fail |
| CC | 2019 | Fail |
| DD | 2020 | Fail |
| EE | 2020 | Fail |
| FF | 2021 | Fail |
| GG | 2021 | Fail |
| HH | 2022 | Fail |
| AA | 2020 | Fail |
| DD | 2021 | Pass |
| EE | 2021 | Fail |
| HH | 2023 | Fail |
| II | 2023 | Fail |
| CC | 2020 | Fail |
| JJ | 2023 | Fail |
| AA | 2021 | Fail |
| CC | 2021 | Pass |
| AA | 2022 | Pass |
| EE | 2022 | Pass |
| KK | 2019 | Fail |
| LL | 2020 | Fail |
| MM | 2021 | Fail |

I need to write an SQL to return the following:

Look at each IDs and see if the status is Fail. What I need to do is then look at that ID and see if that person has applied again in the following years and if so what the result has been.
Eventually, I need to return the IDs of the people who have applied and failed but have passed by reapplying in subsequent years.

To demonstrate for example ID AA failed in 2019,2020,2021 but passed in 2022 so I need to return ID AA and the years they applied and failed and the year they eventually passed preferably in order so that the year they passed will be the last row for that particular ID in this case 2022 which they passed.

I also need to show any multiple applicants and the year of applications and statuses only for duplicated IDs who have always failed.
I need to ignore anyone who has only applied once during all the years.

I  hope I am clear about what I need to achieve

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Google Bigquery doesn't use Transact-SQL. I've removed the conflicting tags; please [edit] your question to (re)add the tags relevant to the product(s) you are actually using.

Comment: Please  tag the question with the targetted SQL server like Mysql, Postgres etc

Comment: Sample data is good (perhaps a little too much?) But you also need to _specify_ the expected result.